# How can I make SQL not execute the query if the field goes negative?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like this:

`UPDATE users SET credits=credits-1000 WHERE id=1`

How do I make this fail if credits goes negative? I want to avoid having to query the database twice just to check for that. I need it to FAIL/return false if it goes negative, not set the credits to zero.

Comment: Why you don't filter this rows with WHERE clause?

Comment: First, what I would like to advise, is not to use `MySQL` at all, but to migrate as fast as possible to `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: @Jacobian can you elaborate? What's wrong with MySQL?

Comment: Well, the list is fact very long: 1) MySQL is far from SQL standard - as far as it is possible (on the contrary, Postgres obeys standars very well) 2) DDL statements (such as CREATE and ALTER) in MySQL autocommit themselves, therefore they can not be part of a larger transaction (but it is ok in almost all popular databases, including Postgres and SQLite) 3) Again there are no DDL triggers in MySQL (in Postgres you have event triggers) 4) At some point, I guess, you will decide to migrate to MariaDB, but you will be disappointed, because MariaDB is not fully compatible with MySQL

Comment: 5) Sometimes Query Execution Plan in MySQL chooses wrong indices - I faced this problem many times, so if you have some sql builder in you application, get ready to meet unexpected behaviour and significant slow down 6) In MySQL 5.6 I faced some behaviour, that tells us, that you can not trust to this database - the problem was that the simplest  SELECT statement with one simple JOIN pulled incorrect data from database. Only when I dropped all indices, it started to pull correct data. So get ready to see in your application some data, that in fact does not exist at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about adding the condition ?

```
   UPDATE users SET credits=credits-1000 WHERE id=1 AND credits > 1000
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this then checking for the number of changed rows to see if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use stored procedure for this purpose. For example

```
CREATE procedure UpdateUserCredit
    @user_id INT,
    @credits INT,
    @op_status BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @op_status = 0

    UPDATE Users
        SET credits = credits - @credits
    WHERE id = @user_id
              AND credits - @credits > 0

    IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
        RETURN
    ELSE
        SET @op_status = 1
END
```

This stored procedure will return `0` in variable `@op_status` if `current credits + @credits` for `@user_id` would be less zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER users_bu BEFORE UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.credits != OLD.credits AND NEW.credits < 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'negative balances are not supported';
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Before the update is written to a row in the table, the new (replacement) value for credits is checked for negative values if that value has been changed by this update.  If it changed, and is now negative, deny the update by throwing an exception.  Requires MySQL Server 5.5 or later as written, but can be made to work with 5.1 or 5.0 with some modifications.

Note that `FOR EACH ROW` doesn't mean the whole table, it means that each row affected by the update is evaluated individually by this code, which will of course typically be just one row.